# Why is importXML not getting new data when refreshed in my Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I'm using:

`=IMPORTXML(($B$1&""&B8)&"/","//div[@class='priceValue ']")`

to retrieve the price value of a stock for a simple sheet. It works fine in retrieving the data (so the formula works in that sense), but the data is not up to date when refreshed.

I found several solutions, but what they basically do is cut the formula and paste it back again. But somehow that doesn't always work (that means it does sometimes). Why is that? I tried closing and opening. Is there a timelimit, that you can't refresh every 10 minutes or something?

Comment: In the spreadsheet settings you can refresh up to minimum every 30 min.

Comment: I have it on minute and/or changes. But still nothing.